# Gmail not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

I am trying to open my gmail account. I am not able to. I am getting this error:

```
This site can’t be reached

mail.google.com refused to connect.
Try:
Reloading the page
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Other services are working fine.
```

One thing I have observed is, when I tried to open gmail in IE, its default language was portuguise(Brasil). When I tried to change it to English, I am getting this error in IE:

```
 The webpage cannot be found 
 HTTP 404  
 Most likely causes:
•There might be a typing error in the address.
•If you clicked on a link, it may be out of date.

   What you can try: 
     Retype the address.  

     Go back to the previous page. 

     Go to  and look for the information you want.  

     More information
```

I have tried clearing browser data. Chrome is up-to-date. So what might be the problem.. Please help me.

Comment: Did you tried with Chrome in  _incognito mode_ ? No problem with cached pages... Just a try

Comment: Yes, of course. I did. still not working.

Comment: Your question is borderline to be off topic here, maybe you can find more help at webapps.stackexchange